# keep_cross_validation_predictions parameter in H2O AutoML

Tags: h2o

I am using H2O AutoML for modelling in R. I found that AutoML supports `keep_cross_validation_predictions` option on h2o web interface page (i.e. Flow) and it doesn't support it when we use R interface to run. Please help me to know why such thing is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the Flow web interface nor R/Python expose the `keep_cross_validation_predictions` option for AutoML. **EDIT:** This parameter is now exposed as of H2O 3.20.0.1.

However, under the hood, all the models will have this set to `TRUE` by default because this is required in order to build the Stacked Ensembles at the end of the AutoML run.

If you wanted to prevent cross validation from occurring you can set `nfolds=0` for AutoML, in which case you will not get any Stacked Ensembles built (though I think the CV predictions will still be saved).

Please see the screen shot below that indicates there is no exposed parameter for `keep_cross_validation_predictions`. Please note, however, that if you are building a regular model in H2O Flow or R or Python you will see the parameter `keep_cross_validation_predictions`.

[image]

Comment: how do I extract these predictions ? I tried `aml@leader@model$cross_validation_predictions` but it's `NULL`. I set `keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE` in my autoML model.